# Blah, blah, blah

Tags: phrases

We use "blah, blah, blah" to mean *"and other words that mean very little"*. For example, *The critics always say, "There’s no melody, the words are stupid, blah, blah, blah."*

What's the origin of *blah, blah, blah?* Is it correct to call it an informal exclamation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is intended to be a meaningless sound. It dates from the start of the 20th century, with printed evidence from 1919.

Compare with other "Bl" words: "blabber" (talk quickly without meaning) "bleat" (the sound of sheep) "blubber" (cry). You see these words are all meaningless voices. There is no certain origin but one hypothesis is that it was influenced by French *blasé* which was in use in English from about 1820.